# Proof of condition for Abelian property

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

I'm currently working through Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra, and I think I'm slowly starting to get a hang of the proofs. Could someone verify if my answer for this question is correct?

> Prove that a group G is abelian if and only if $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b$ in G.

*Proof:* If a group is Abelian then $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}.$

The reverse: $$ (ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1} \implies (ab)^{-1}(ba) = e \implies (ba)^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$$ and we are done.

Comment: It seems fine. Good job.

Comment: Why not ending with $\implies ba=ab$ (instead of $\implies (ba)^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$)? That is more clear.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, the answer is excellent.

Comment: For a more complete proof, you can declare that $a,b\in G$.

Comment: I am going to disagree (but only slightly) that it is okay as is. The condition of commutivity is $ab = ba$, not $(ba)^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$, So it would be better if in your last set, you instead multiplied both sides of $(ab)^{-1}(ba) = e$ on the left by $ab$, and therefore arrived at the conclusion $ba = ab$.

Comment: Not quite done. $(ba)^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}\implies ba=ab.$